# Associating a validation error to multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have one validation that operates on multiple attributes.  For example, I am storing the "length" of a certain model as two separate integers :feet, :inches and I want to make sure that the length is not zero, i.e. both :feet and :inches are non-negative and at least one is positive.  This is easy, for example by adding

```
errors.add_to_base('invalid length') unless (feet >= 0 and inches >= 0 and feet+inches > 0)
```

to my validate method (along with separate checks for integrality and inches < 12).

But I want to associate the error to the fields `:inches` and `:feet` so that when there is an error both fields in the form get highlighted.   Right now the only thing I see to do is call `errors.add()` twice, once for each field.  But I am generated this model using scaffolding so this would require spitting out two error messages, one for each call of `errors.add()`.  Also in the form itself I would like to use a single label "Length" next to both of these fields and I would like that label to get highlighted when there is an error.

Do I need to ditch the scaffolding stuff to achieve this? How?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way to handle this is to create a virtual attribute called "length" and set the error on it instead of on the component fields. In other words, create a custom validation that checks for the various error conditions, builds up a string (in case there are multiple errors) and then adds the string to `errors[:length]`. The form will need to display the inline errors for the length attribute in a place where it is visually associated with the "feet" and "inches" fields. Obviously you'll need to abandon the scaffolding to do this.

There's tutorial for virtual attributes in [Railscasts episode 16](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes), which is a little stale by now (2007!) but still watchable. Just imagine it as a classic black and white film...

Comment: `The form will need to display the inline errors for the length attribute in a place where it is visually associated with the "feet" and "inches" fields. ` How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the errors on a new label, and then nest the labels in your view.  This lets you highlight each field individually (separate error messages) or both together (a single error message).

In your model, you don't actually have to create a corresponding virtual attribute.  You can just set the errors like this:

```
errors.add(:length, 'invalid length'    ) unless (feet >= 0 && inches >= 0)
errors.add(:inches, 'too big'           ) unless (inches < 12)
errors.add(:feet,   'cannot be negative') unless (feet < 0)
```

Then, nest the labels in your view:

```
- # (This is Haml.  If you use erb, I'm sure you can figure it out!)
= f.label :length do
  = f.label feet, "Feet:"
= f.text_field :feet

= f.label :length do
  = f.label inches, "Inches:"
= f.text_field :inches
```

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this code, but I've got something very similar in my codebase.  This is with rails 3.1.11